# How can I manipulate the REST API GET generated by YANG in Opendaylight?

Tags: opendaylight

PUT, DELETE, POST can be operated as shown below.

By the way, I do not know how to do GET.

Please help me.

```
// PUT & DELETE (mapped to WRITE, DELETE of MD-SAL)
public void onDataTreeChanged(Collection<DataTreeModification<GreetingRegistry>> changes) {
  for(DataTreeModification<GreetingRegistry> change: changes) {
     DataObjectModification<GreetingRegistry> rootNode = change.getRootNode();
     if(rootNode.getModificationType() == WRITE) {
        ...
     }
     else if(rootNode.getModificationType() == DELETE) {
        ...
     }
}


// POST (mapped to RPC of MD-SAL)
public Future<RpcResult<HelloWorldOutput>> helloWorld(HelloWorldInput input) 
{
  HelloWorldOutputBuilder helloBuilder = new HelloWorldOutputBuilder();
  helloBuilder.setGreeting("Hello " + input.getName());
  return RpcResultBuilder.success(helloBuilder.build()).buildFuture();
}

// GET (???)
How should I implement it?
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to implement anything for GET in your code, when you want to read from YANG modeled MD-SAL data, the GET method is be available by default, and returns whatever data you ask for in the URL. It is important to point to the correct URL.

If you want to do some processing on data before returning it to the user, you can use RPCs with POST, and do the processing in the RPC based methods. In your example above, you could pot the search keys into `HelloWorldInput`, do the processing in `helloWorld()`, and return results in `HelloWorldOutput`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I'm trying to manipulate the DB to return data when I make a GET request.
Is this impossible?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. You don't get a notification when data is read using GET, so you cannot react to it. That's why I recommend RPC if you want to manipulate your DB on read.